# identify individual devices from aggregate traffic of router

Tags: networking, router, ip, tcp, tcpip

Is it possible and if yes how to identify individual devices (laptop vs. mobile phone vs TV) when listening to the aggregate traffic of a wifi router?

Assumption: all devices of interest are connected to the same (home) router, i.e. setup could look like below

```
me(outside)--ipv4_NAT----router(a,b,c)
```

where `me` would be able to listen to the aggregate traffic of all devices (but not being connected to any management ports of the router, only the usage traffic is available).

## edit

improved diagram

Comment: I assume (a, b, c) refers to 3 devices and all of them NAT'd into the same IP? Can you sniff between the NAT and the router instead?

Comment: This diagram confuses me. Is the IPv4 NAT in a separate box from the Wi-Fi router? Is "me" on the public side of the NAT, or is it on the private side? I have a feeling what you're really asking has everything to do with NAT and nothing to do with Wi-Fi. I think you're really asking "When there may be multiple devices behind a v4 NAT and I can only sniff on the public side, can I identify the devices behind the NAT?". And the answer is "sometimes yes". There's plenty of research out there on NAT detection.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ... it depends. I'm not sure if I understand your diagram correctly.  Since you mention wifi, I'm not sure if those devices are directly connected to the router via wire and you are connected to the router via wifi, or the "wifi" data is a totally unrelated fact.

There are two scenarios that I can think of:

1. You are on the same subnet than those devices and behind the *same* NAT:

If you happen to know the IP address assigned to each host, then just check the IP header. If the IPs are dynamically assigned though DHCP, in the configuration page of your router there is usually a page that displays a table (or maybe a graphic or animation) that translates hostnames to assigned IPs .
Alternatively, since you hint you are in a home network, you could just assign static IPs to all devices.

Otherwise, you could try to lookup the MAC addresses, extract their [OUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier) and try to identify the hosts based on the hardware manufacturer of the NIC. Maybe you can use a tool like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248769/command-line-tool-to-obtain-oui-vendor-info-from-mac-address/248775).

2. Those devices are under NAT behind the router and you are on the *other side*

Unless you can deduce it by analyzing the traffic (packet lengths, payloads, transport protocol, protocols they use, ...), I can't think of an easy way you can identify them. That's the whole point of NAT.

Comment: the case I am thinking about is 2

Comment: Then, as @Spiff said, you may be able to identify them depending on the type of traffic you observe. For example, for plain HTTP you may identify the devices based on the browser's user agent. However, most devices use encrypted traffic now, so you have to identify them based on traffic patterns.

Comment: Do you know of some tools or literature performing this type of analysis?